# "List index of out of range error " during inference ( Show up this week )

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, retinanet

i have been using same notebook on colab for more than 2 months with same weights and dependencies. It started to give me error this week. I didn't change anything. It suprisingly started to give me error. while loading the model. Could you please help me ?

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d80d5bc75b82> in <module>()
      3 
      4 # load retinanet model
----> 5 model = models.load_model(model_path, backbone_name='resnet50')
      6 model = models.convert_model(model)
      7 

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in process_node(layer, node_data)
   1222           add_unprocessed_node(layer, node_data)
   1223           return
-> 1224         inbound_node = inbound_layer._inbound_nodes[inbound_node_index]
   1225         input_tensors.append(
   1226             nest.flatten(inbound_node.outputs)[inbound_tensor_index])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the repo ( Fizyr_Keras_retinanet) :https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAnFg.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @syln21, As suggested by Amal K, without code it is very difficult to provide solution.If you can provide standalone code here rather than link to replicate your issue? we can try to help you. Thanks!